# German work visa and Italian Schengen visa, which visa to use?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, work, long-stay-visas

I have my latest German work visa as well as a valid Italian Schengen visa For my German employment registration can I travel from Italy, or first do I need to Travel to Germany?

I will be traveling from India.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the German work visa is a type D national visa. This visa grants you the ability to go to Germany for the amount of time specified in the visa, as well as to other schengen states following the 90/180 rule ([according to another member state](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/stranieri/ingressosoggiornoinitalia/visto_ingresso/tipologie_visto_durata.html)).

You may enter the schengen area with this visa. If the border guard asks, say that you will be transiting (or staying for a few days, depending on your plans), then go on to Germany.

I would not recommend attempting to enter with the Italian tourist or business visa, because tourism or business is not the purpose of your trip.